# Turn off layers/folders in Google embedded javascript maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm using the Google Javascript Maps API to embed a map with KML data with the oft-used snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function detectBrowser() {
    var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
    var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map-canvas");
    if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
      mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
      //mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
      mapdiv.style.height = '600px';
    } else {
      mapdiv.style.width = '600px';
      mapdiv.style.height = '600px';
    }
  }
  function initialize() {
    detectBrowser();
    var mapOptions = { gestureHandling: 'cooperative' };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ 
      url: "https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=19vJ5I6283iXcFINgp4U_JnqmbiXMySwD",
      map: map,
    });
    georssLayer.setMap(map);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div style="width: 600px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;" id="map-canvas"></div>
```

I want to use a KML that has multiple folders (or "layers" in MyMaps language) but I want to be able to select which folders to show.  Is there any way to load KML with KmlLayer and then turn on/off folders by name?

Comment: I think essentially you'd need to know the structre of the XML file initially so that you can craft links/buttons to invoke the visibility of individual `Folder` contents but to do so you need to be able to read it. A `kmz` file is basically a zipped XML file - with PHP it is easy to read/parse but not so with Javascript unless you use a special library (jsZip.js etc)

Comment: I've not seen reference to native methods (Google Maps/KML) for manipulating the display of items that I can recall. If you have PHP I'd go that route and programmatically add the layers once you have parsed the KML data

Comment: KmlLayer doesn't support this (last I checked).  You either need to implement the "folders" as seperate KML files displayed by separate KmlLayer objects, or use a third party KML parser (which would have performance implications)

Comment: So is the 'google.maps.KmlLayer' just an XML file that has some ability to be edited that would require some javascript?  Or do I need an XML parser that I then do editing on and use setMap() on?  (and does setMap take XML or does it need to be converted in some way?)